# Finding a vlan open ports

Tags: networking, network-programming, udp, ports

I m developing a java app to share information via udp connections(it s just experimental). The problem is I am working within a vlan so my program cant "see" outside it. Is there any way to know which port in the vlan is open, so i can use go trough it?

The network in general is a closed circuit, internet isolated and with a vlan, where i m.

Thanks

Comment: You need to provide more information about your app, where is it sending data, is it receiving any data back, etc.

Comment: Im sending data from a computer inside the vlan to another one outside it, but data never arrives. The app is a basic example about udp connections via Java, using DatagramSocket and DatagramPacket.
Fun fact i saw some mates playing Call of Duty Modern Warfare 3 and the server is outside the vlan, but any client inside vlan can access to it without search for open ports in vlan. They just run the game and done.
How is possible that???

Comment: @Krlos9108, you shouldn't need to look for open ports in vlan. Two vlan's are two different LAN's. You need a router to route packets from one vlan to another. Do you have this setup?